# Remove orphans with JPA/Hibernate in opposite direction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one, orphan-removal

I'm struggling with this problem:

It is quite difficult in JPA/Hibernate to remove an orphaned child from multiple parents.
When the relation is: multiple-parent > multiple-children there is no issue and orphanRemoval = true works as expected.

But in our situation we have multiple parent locations with a single child city. How to do this?
Perhaps reversing the relation? A 'parent'-city has multiple 'child'-locations or something? How would this work if the 'child'-location is also referenced by 'parent'-provinces for example.

I tried to Google for answers but didn't came across this one.